# Excel export with caption before exported data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was wondering if it's possible to include text above the exported data in an Excel file using Kendo UI?

For example, I wish to include a description of the data above the actual data exported:

> Data selected using dates between 1 Jan 2011 to 1 Sep 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a handler to the excelExport event of the Grid and manually prepend the row to the exported workbook. The approach won't work if the exported file is filterable.

```
excelExport: function(e) {
  e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.unshift({
    cells: [{
        value: "Data selected using dates between 1 Jan 2011 to 1 Sep 2011"
    }]
  });
}
```